# How did this person gain possession of the Infinity Stones?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the final fight with Thanos, Tony Stark has a struggle with Thanos to get the gauntlet off him. Later it is shown that the stones are now with Tony on his suit.

The question is, how did he get it off the gauntlet and onto his suit?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nanotech most likely, possibly with a filament shape

Since *Infinity War*, Tony has been going around with nano armor able to shapeshift into various stuff; for instance, a shield when it was introduced:

And at the start of the big fight with Thanos in *Endgame*

> Into an electric transformer of sorts, to channel Thor's lightning into a blast in Thanos' face.

Contrary to the previous armors which could,  for instance, deploy from a suitcase, nano doesn't seem to have a "mechanical" comportment and can shape itself into whatever is needed; why not some filaments retrieving the Stones? Although I don't have a visual, I seem to remember the nano "reforming" itself under the Stones on Tony's arm, supporting this theory.

Consider that Thanos wears the gauntlet and has gone through quite the battle, so he is unlikely to feel them being taken away.

Comment: Although we don't see the gauntlet being constructed, it's reasonable to assume that it is also made from the same nanotech that the suit is. This would mean that Tony would be able to reshape the gauntlet as he saw fit, just like he does the suit. The combination of the two would easily allow him to move the stones from the gauntlet into the suit.

Comment: @aleppke - That was what I assumed happened.  Maybe make it into a separate answer so it can be upvoted, too?

Comment: @aleppke we do see the gauntled actively re-shaping itself when Hulk was about to put it on. It did that in a way consistent with how the nanotech Iron Man armour does it. Moreover, it *looks* like the Iron Man armour.

Comment: Iron Man does something similar to what you have in the spoiler in the first Avengers movie. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eZP30Vx4Wc It seems to be a property of the Arc Reactor, not the nanotech.